Wireguard peer (and not server) as exit node
I have Wireguard server in country A with several clients. Let's say client 1, which is my Linux laptop, has IP address 10.10.7.9 and client 2, which is a Mikrotik router has IP address 10.10.7.155.
Mikrotik is located in country B and does not have default gateway set to Wireguard server in country A. So devices connected to this Mikrotik use public IP from country B, but Mikrotik is accessible from my laptop through VPN (at VPN IP address 10.10.7.155).
Now, I would like to use Mikrotik as default gateway for my laptop. So I will be accessing internet with my laptop with IP from country B.
How to do that?

Strictly as stated – one client cannot use another client as 'gateway' through WireGuard or any other IP tunnel, because it does not have a direct L2 connection to that peer. It would be trivial to do this through an Ethernet tunnel such as OpenVPN-TAP or ZeroTier, but not possible with an IP tunnel – the laptop is only able route through "other end of the tunnel" but it cannot choose a specific host.
Instead, the server needs to have all of the routing configuration done, while the laptop needs to continue using the central server (or rather, its WireGuard interface in general) as its 'default gateway'.
On the server, it would make things easier if the Mikrotik had a separate WireGuard tunnel (i.e. a separate wg1 on a different UDP port).

You first need to change the [Peer] configuration for Mikrotik to have 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 as its AllowedIPs, so that WireGuard would internally route all "Internet" packets towards that peer.

But you also need to make sure the WG config tool (networkd or wg-quick) does not copy that into the server's main routing table, as wg-quick generally does so by default; you would specify a custom Table= to turn this off – and to make it add the route to a separate routing table.
(This is the main reason for having a separate tunnel config for the Mikrotik; it would let you move this specific route without affecting all regular clients' routes. Though in simple setups, a shared tunnel should still work.)

Once you have the 0.0.0.0/0 route in a separate table, use ip rule to hook it up – make the server select that routing table for packets 'from' client 1. (This should result in packets from wg0 going right back into the same wg0.)

When the packets reach the Mikrotik, it most likely should apply src-nat (masquerade) to them.
Of course, the Mikrotik itself cannot be set up to also use WireGuard as its default route.


At every step, test using Wireshark, tcpdump, or /tool/sniffer/quick to make sure the packets actually go where you need them to go.

Hmm, maybe my question was not detailed enough. Here is what I am trying to do: https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=160219

The answer remains the same. Wireguard (due to being an IP-only tunnel) doesn't allow you to use another system "two hops away" as a gateway – it doesn't provide the L2 connectivity necessary for via 10.10.7.155 to work (more specifically, there's no place in the packets to indicate the via). Your only option is to go through the server first, and have the server route through the Mikrotik next.
